# Soft keyboard is not visible on Android with Qt 5.15 on any input

Tags: android, android-virtual-keyboard, qtvirtualkeyboard, qt5.15

We migrated from 5.12.9 to 5.15.2 and now soft Android keyboard is not visible (does not popup) on active focus for any of our inputs or text fields. Is it a bug ([QTBUG-88069](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88069)) or some workaround exists?

Following [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39507526/630169) or [setting/clearing window flags](https://forum.qt.io/post/329693) does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was obvious because of following lines:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
#endif
```

Changed to

```
#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX) && !defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
#endif
```

as on Android both constants are defined: `Q_OS_LINUX` and `Q_OS_ANDROID`. And voila: Android keyboard works! :)